# Detectar líneas y obtener parámetros de líneas en imagen en Python

Tags: python, imagen, opencv, scikit-learn

Estoy pasando código desde MATLAB a Python usando OpenCV y skimage para detectar en una imagen sus líneas. El código en MATLAB es el siguiente:

```
function [rect, pt] = detecta_hoja(im)

    % [rect, pt] = detectaa_hoja(im)
    %
    % DETECTA_HOJA Localiza a partir de la imagen de contorno im la recta
    % correspondiente a la hoja de la llave, devolviendo los parámetros
    % de recta pendiente (rect.m) y ordenada en el origen (rect.n), así como
    % los puntos detectados de la recta pt.
    %
    
        %   Factores configurables
        k_nfill = 0.1;
        k_minl = 0.1;
        
        %   Tamaño de imagen de entrada
        im_tam = size(im, [1 2]);
        
        %   Cálculo de parámetros
        nfill = k_nfill*min(im_tam);
        minl = k_minl*min(im_tam);
        
        %   Obtiene el contorno de la llave
        im_edge = edge(im,'canny');
    
        %   Aplica la transformada de Hough
        [H,theta,rho] = hough(im_edge);
        %   Busca los picos
        P = houghpeaks(H,10);
        %   Obtiene las lineas
        lines = houghlines(im_edge, theta, rho, P,...
                           'FillGap', nfill, 'MinLength', minl);
        
        %   Comprueba que se han encontrado lineas
        if ~isempty(lines)
            
            %   Obtener coordenadas de lineas
            a = reshape([lines.point1],2,[])';
            b = reshape([lines.point2],2,[])';
            
            %   Obtener distancias a partir de los puntos
            d = sqrt((a(:,1) - b(:,1)).^2 + (a(:,2) - b(:,2)).^2);
            
            %   Se obtiene la linea más larga
            [~,i] = max(d);
            a = a(i,:); b = b(i,:);
            %   Ajuste de indexación
            a = fliplr(a); b = fliplr(b);  
            
            %   Ordenar ambos puntos según criterio:
            %   - a siempre está a arriba de b
            %   - Si están ambos a la misma altura, a estará a la derecha
            if (a(1) > b(1)) || ((a(1) == b(1)) && (a(2) < b(2)))
                aux = a;
                a = b;
                b = aux;
            end
    
            %   Obtención de parámetros de recta
            %   Cálculo de la pendiente
            m = (a(1)-b(1))/(a(2)-b(2));
            %   Cálculo de ordenada en el origen
            if isinf(m)
                n = a(2);
            else
                n = a(1)-(m*a(2));
            end
            
            %   Creación de variables de salida
            rect.m = m;
            rect.n = n;
            pt = {a, b};
    
        else
            %   En caso de no encontrar ninguna línea de hoja de llave
            error("No se han encontrado la hoja de llave en el recorte proporcionado.");
        end
    end
```

Parece ser que en Python usando OpenCV y skimage no existe la transformada estándar de Hough, así que he usado las siguientes funciones:

```
# DETECTA HOJA
k_nfill = 0.1
k_minl = 0.1

# Tamaño de imagen de entrada
im_tam = cllave.shape

# Cálculo de parámetros
nfill = round(k_nfill*min(im_tam))
minl = round(k_minl*min(im_tam))

# Cálculo del contorno
im_edge = canny(cllave)
out, angles, rho = hough_line(im_edge)
lines = probabilistic_hough_line(im_edge, theta=angles, line_length=minl, line_gap=nfill)
```

En MATLAB me salen 10 líneas, con sus respectivos puntos, y además me devuelve los valores theta y rho, en cambio en Python me devuelve 145 líneas solo con sus respectivos puntos. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo asemejar ese resultado a Python para poder computar los siguientes parámetros tal y como se explica en la función de MATLAB.

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, estoy a punto de terminar mi TFG y toda ayuda por mínima que sea será enormemente recibida, cualquier duda o consulta estoy a vuestra entera disposición.

Comment: openCV en Python sí tiene la transformada de Hough para detectar líneas [ver aquí](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) posdata: la pregunta es muy abierta, casi que se pide que traspasen el código de Matlab a python, casi.

Comment: usando el código de MATLAB me da como 10 pares de puntos, usando el de Python me da (en función de si lo uso por defecto o determino un rango de angulos) 42 o 145 pares. Mi pregunta ya se reduce a lo siguiente: ¿es mejor detectar más rectas para computar mejor al final la imagen o no? Lo que estoy haciendo al final es detectar las rectas del contorno de la imagen para determinar su contorno.